# Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I know perfectly well that this question has already been asked but none of the answers helped me. The "webController" it mentions in the stacktrace is no present, it existed before. I hope you can help me..

**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource

[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'webController' method

com.example.demo.controllers.WebController#showForm(PersonForm)
to {GET [/register]}: There is already 'registerController' bean method

**

com.example.demo.controllers.RegisterController#showForm(PersonForm) mapped.

POM:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.4.5
 

com.example
demo
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
demo
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>1.8</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-validation


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-security


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


org.thymeleaf.extras
thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Class:

@Controller
public class LoginController implements WebMvcConfigurer {

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/a").setViewName("results");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/access-denied").setViewName("accessDenied");
}

@GetMapping
public String goToHome(Principal principal){
    if(principal.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("admin"))
    return "Homepage";
    else return "start";

}
```

}

@Controller
public class RegisterController implements WebMvcConfigurer {

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/results").setViewName("results");
}

@Autowired
RegisterRepository registerRepository;

@GetMapping(value = "/register")
public String showForm(PersonForm personForm) {
    return "formValidation";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/register")
public String checkPersonInfo(@Valid PersonForm personForm, BindingResult bindingResult,
                              @RequestParam(value = "nome") String nome,
                              @RequestParam(value = "cognome") String cognome,
                              @RequestParam(value = "dataNascita") String dataNascita,
                              @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "formValidation";
    } else if (registerRepository.findByCognome(cognome) == null) {
        Utente utente = new Utente(0, nome, cognome, LocalDate.parse(dataNascita), false, password);
        registerRepository.save(utente);
        UserDetails user =
                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username(utente.getCognome())
                        .password(utente.getPassword())
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        WebSecurityConfig.inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(user);

        return "results";
    }
    else return "errorRegisterPerson";


}

@PostMapping(value = "/results")
public String returnResults(){
    return "results";
}
```

}

@Controller
public class ShowUserController {

```
@Autowired
RegisterRepository registerRepository;

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping(value = "/Users")
public String showUsersDB(Model model){
    List<Utente> lista = registerRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

    return "Users";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/searchUser")
public String searchUserForName(@RequestParam(value = "name")String nome, Model model){
    List<Utente> lista = Collections.singletonList(userRepository.findByCognome(nome));
    model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

    return "Users";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/addUser")
public String addUser(@RequestParam String name,
                      @RequestParam String surname,
                      @RequestParam String date,
                      @RequestParam String password,
                      Model model){

    LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(date);
    Utente utente = new Utente(0,name,surname,data,false,password);
    registerRepository.save(utente);

    UserDetails user =
            User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                    .username(utente.getCognome())
                    .password(utente.getPassword())
                    .roles("USER")
                    .build();

    WebSecurityConfig.inMemoryUserDetailsManager.createUser(user);

    List<Utente> lista = registerRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

    return "Users";

}

@GetMapping(value = "/prova/{password}")
public String show(@PathVariable("password")String password, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("oldPassword",password);

    return "UserProfile";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/changeUserPsw/{oldPsw}")
public String changePsw(@PathVariable("oldPsw")String oldPsw,@RequestParam(value = "password")String password,
                        Model model){
    userRepository.setUserPassword(password,oldPsw);

    List<Utente> lista = registerRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

    return "Users";
}
```

}

@Controller
public class UserController {

```
@Autowired
RegisterRepository registerRepository;

@GetMapping("/ciaooo")
public String showUserDB(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("lista",registerRepository.findAll());
    return "Users";
}
```

}

@Controller
public class VehiclesController {

```
@Autowired
VehiclesRepository vehiclesRepository;


@GetMapping(value = "/Vehicles")
public String showVehiclesDB(Model model){
    List<Mezzo> lista = vehiclesRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

    return "Vehicles";
```

}

```
@GetMapping(value = "/searchVehicles")
public String searchVehiclesForName(@RequestParam(value = "name")String nome, Model model){
    List<Mezzo> lista = Collections.singletonList(vehiclesRepository.findByModello(nome));
    model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

    return "Users";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/prova/{targa}")
public String showTarga(@PathVariable("targa")String targa, Model model){

    model.addAttribute("oldTarga",targa);

    return "VehicleProfile";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/changeVehicleTarga/{vecchiaTarga}")
public String changeTarga(@PathVariable("vecchiaTarga")String oldTarga,@RequestParam(value = "targa")String targa,
                        Model model){
    vehiclesRepository.setVehicleTarga(targa,oldTarga);

    List<Mezzo> lista = vehiclesRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

    return "Vehicles";
}

@PostMapping(value = "/addVehicle")
public String addVehicle(@RequestParam(value = "modello")String modello,
                         @RequestParam(value = "casaCostr")String casaCostr,
                         @RequestParam(value = "tiplogia")String tipologia,
                         @RequestParam(value = "targa")String targa,
                         @RequestParam(value = "annoImm")int annoImm,
                         Model model){

    Mezzo mezzo = new Mezzo(0,targa,modello,casaCostr,tipologia,annoImm);
    vehiclesRepository.save(mezzo);

    List<Mezzo> lista = vehiclesRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("lista", lista);

    return "Vehicles";

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue telling like you have same for two methods that's `Ambiguous mapping Cannot map`

Within ithe RegisterController you have same for get and post give some different name for those mapping methods.

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when you have multiple request mapping with the same name and exactly the same HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

In your case, you must have declared a `GET /register` endpoint mapping before in another file.

Replace this `GET /register` endpoint with some prefix for example `/vehicle/register` to make it distinguishable from the previous mapping. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for response. I resolved this problem doing a build pilots, MAVEN -> Clean Maven and next install. 
I think that in memory there was another class that i removed but in memory not.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been resolved with: Maven -> clean Maven and next install